# "gulp-sass": 2.1.1 - how to log errors at compile time

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using "gulp-sass": 2.1.1 to compile my project. I'm having some issues identifying where the missing files are from. Whats the best way to logout this error information. Is there a flag or something I can set whilst compiling?

Jimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `.on('error', ...)` in your task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Comment: Hi There, I did try this but it doesn't seem to work. I get the stack trace in the console but I'd like to get the context of where the file is failing. Seems like it's very difficult to do this. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only logging option I know of. There used to be a `sass({errLogToConsole: true})`, but I don't think that exists anymore.

Comment: My implementation is custom, probably the reason it's not working for me. I did read through the docs, before posting... and saw the implementation you posted.